# Error when converting String to Long in beanshell processor in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to convert a String to a Long integer, then do some calculations, then convert back to String. The entire code in the beanshell postprocessor is here (depositamount and imagecount are variables already known in JMeter):

```
Long ttl=Long.valueOf(vars.get("depositamount"));
Long med=Long.valueOf(vars.get("depositamount"));
Long intermediate=med/vars.get("imagecount");

String depamt=intermediate.toString();

vars.put("depositamount",depamt);

Double tlnlast=ttl-depamt * (vars.get("imagecount")-1);

vars.put("lastamt",tlnlast.toString());

vars.put("loopcounter","1");
```

However, when I run this, I get an error: ``` ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``Long ttl=Long.valueOf(vars.get("depositamount")); Long med=Long.valueOf(vars.get . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Long.valueOf ``` . I've  tried to use `Long.parseLong`in place of the valueOf, but the same error gets thrown, with the "parseLong" taking the place of "valueOf".
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `Long intermediate=med/vars.get("imagecount");` Not that this is your problem, but are you dividing by a string here?

Comment: More string math here: `(vars.get("imagecount")-1)`

Comment: Thank you for finding those. Would have gotten errors there once past this question. I'll have to account for that, too.

Comment: One of the problems with jmeter beanshell blocks is that it tends to swallow the actual exception and throws this generic exception that doesn't really help you chase down the issue. Can you stick your code in a try-catch block and in catch, log actual stacktrace?

Comment: Well, I fixed the other string issues you pointed out above, and then put in the try-catch, but it didn't throw any issues anymore. It was probably trying to do the string math and threw a generic error. I'll have to remember the try-catch trick with jmeter in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- From performance perspective it's better to use [Long.parseLong(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)) method
- Double check your `med/vars.get("imagecount")` and `vars.get("imagecount")-1` methods as `vars.get()` returns [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). If your `imagecount` variable has different type - use [vars.getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject(java.lang.String)) method instead
- as per [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article, if you add `debug();` directive to the very beginning of your Beanshell script - you'll be able to see a lot of debugging information in STDOUT which should be enough to troubleshoot any issue.

Comment: `valueOf()` uses `parseLong()` underneath. There is no performance difference.  see: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#507